# Check if column name of a pandas df starts with "name" and split that column based on existing white space

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
df = pd.read_json('{"id":{"0":"21 Delta","1":"38 Bravo","2":"Charlie 37","3":"Alpha 56"},"name_1":{"0":"Tom","1":"Nick","2":"Chris","3":"David 56"},"name_2":{"0":"Peter 17","1":"Emma 53","2":"Jeff 11","3":"Oscar"},"name_3":{"0":"Jeffrey","1":"Olivier 12","2":null,"3":null},"name_4":{"0":"Henry 23","1":null,"2":null,"3":null}}') 
df

    id           name_1      name_2     name_3       name_4
0   21 Delta     Tom         Peter 17   Jeffrey      Henry 23 
1   38 Bravo     Nick        Emma 53    Olivier 12   None
2   Charlie 37   Chris       Jeff 11    None         None
3   Alpha 56     David 56    Oscar      None         None
```

What I would like to do is to iterate over the columns in this df and check if the column name starts with `name`. If so, I would like to add the number after the white space in each row of that particular column in an extra column called `age_` which increments by one like so:

```
    id          name_1   name_2    name_3     name_4    age_1  age_2  age_3  age_4
0   21 Delta    Tom      Peter 17  Jeffrey    Henry 23  None   17     None   23
1   38 Bravo    Nick     Emma 53   Olivier 12 None      None   53     12     None
2   Charlie 37  Chris    Jeff 11   None       None      None   11     None   None    
3   Alpha 56    David 56 Oscar     None       None      56     None   None   None
```

So far I came up with this, but I struggle how to get to the end result:

```
for column in df.columns:
    if column.startswith("name"):
        age = df[column].str.split(" ").str.get(1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
ages = (df.filter(like="name")
          .apply(lambda col: col.str.extract(r" (\d+)$", expand=False))
          .rename(columns=lambda c: c.replace("name", "age")))
```

- get the "name" involving columns
- for each of them, extract the numbers near end with a regex
- column names are still "name_*", so replace "name" with "age" there

and lastly join with the original frame to get

```py
>>> df.join(ages)

           id    name_1    name_2      name_3    name_4 age_1 age_2 age_3 age_4
0    21 Delta       Tom  Peter 17     Jeffrey  Henry 23   NaN    17   NaN    23
1    38 Bravo      Nick   Emma 53  Olivier 12      None   NaN    53    12  None
2  Charlie 37     Chris   Jeff 11        None      None   NaN    11  None  None
3    Alpha 56  David 56     Oscar        None      None    56   NaN  None  None
```

Comment: Thanks! What should the regex be if I would like to extract the part _before_ the white space?

Comment: hi @sampeterson, it could be `r"^(\S+)"`, i.e., capture anything non-space from the beginning until a space.

Answer (score 1):

Besides [Mustafa Aydın's approach](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75236733/19290081). Here is the fixed version of your `for-loop`

```py
for column in df.columns:
    if column.startswith("name"):
        age = f"age_{column[-1]}"
        df[age] = df[column].str.extract(r"(\d+)")
        
print(df)
```

---

```
           id    name_1    name_2      name_3    name_4 age_1 age_2 age_3 age_4
0    21 Delta       Tom  Peter 17     Jeffrey  Henry 23   NaN    17   NaN    23
1    38 Bravo      Nick   Emma 53  Olivier 12      None   NaN    53    12   NaN
2  Charlie 37     Chris   Jeff 11        None      None   NaN    11   NaN   NaN
3    Alpha 56  David 56     Oscar        None      None    56   NaN   NaN   NaN
```

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately this doesn't work if my numbers in the column names exceed >10